# Getting errors in an sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, average

Problem -> Select all orders that are greater than the average for October 4.

Table Schema:

```
mysql> desc orders;
+-------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ONUM  | int   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AMT   | float | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ODATE | date  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| CNUM  | int   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SNUM  | int   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have tried a number of queries for this(around 10), but still not able to get through.
Some of the Queries that I have tried :

```
select outer.onum, outer.amt from orders outer where outer.amt>any(select avg(o.amt) from orders o group by o.odate having o.odate='1996-10-04') and outer.odate<>'1996-10-04';
select outer.onum, outer.amt from orders as outer where outer.amt>any(select avg(o.amt) as 04_avg from orders o group by o.odate having o.odate='1996-10-04') and outer.odate<>'1996-10-04';
```

Still, no success. Can anybody help me out? Plus, can anybody explain to the usage of aggregate function in relation to sub-query and the proper usage of correlated sub-queries and nested queries. Internet has not been much of help.
Thank You.

Comment: Greater what than the average of what?

Comment: any order from orders table, whose amount is > than avg(of orders on 1996-10-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the average of `1996-10-04` with this query:

```
SELECT AVG(AMT) 
FROM orders
WHERE ODATE = '1996-10-04'
```

You can use the above query in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE AMT > (
  SELECT AVG(AMT) 
  FROM orders
  WHERE ODATE = '1996-10-04'
)
```

If you want to filter out rows of `1996-10-04` you can add:

```
AND ODATE <> '1996-10-04'
```

Comment: Additionally, the mistake that I was not able to find was that, i was using the word "outer" as an alias for the outer table, which is a keyword SQL uses for joins. I realised that as soon as i removed the alias. Thanks, btw.

Answer (score 1):

This also works. Changed the alias of the outer table, and used a word other than "outer".

```
select outer4.onum, outer4.amt from orders as outer4 where outer4.amt >any(select avg(o.amt) from orders o group by o.odate having o.odate='1996-10-04') and outer4.odate<>'1996-10-04';

select onum, amt from orders where amt >(select avg(o.amt) from orders o group by o.odate having o.odate='1996-10-04') and odate<>'1996-10-04';
```